# Installing public npm packages from the GitHub package registry

Tags: github

1.I publish a **public** package in an organization repo.
The repo link : https://github.com/JX3BOX/jx3box-config/packages/141887

2.And I wanna install the package from another repo.
I had set the dependencies in the package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@jx3box/jx3box-config": "^1.0.3",
```

and I created a file named `.npmrc` ,and set :

```
@jx3box:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
```

3.When I use github actions to build
There is an error occur

```
Running build scripts... npm install && npm run build
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Basic realm="GitHub Package Registry"
```

It means maybe I need auth.But This is an public package.Is it should be auth too?

4.Now I had to prepend a line in the file `.npmrc`,just like

```
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=<mytoken>
```

But how can I set it in the actions .
or because this is a public pkg,how can I don't need any auth?

---

Thanks a lot!! ^_^

Comment: Is there any more information you can share such that others could reproduce your problem?

Comment: I try to modify the .npmrc and define the token, and it works . but I think it's not an appropriate way

Comment: I'm very sorry. I really checkout the relatived github docs.But I thought maybe just it had another way,maybe just the documents didn't update yet.But Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably solved but posting anyway because this question ranks high on Google.

From the GitHub Docs:

> You need an access token to publish, install, and delete private, internal, and public packages. You can use a personal access token (classic) to authenticate to GitHub Packages or the GitHub API.[...]

You cannot install packages (even public ones) from the GitHub npm registry without being authenticated.

More details and multiple authentication methods here:

https://docs.github.com/en/packages/guides/configuring-npm-for-use-with-github-packages#authenticating-to-github-packages

Comment: "You cannot install packages (even public ones)" - This can't be true, I just signed out of npm and github locally, and I am still able to install a public github package.

Comment: UPDATE: I just saw i had credentials in my ~/.npmrc file. When i deleted that file, i get the error. So you are right.

Comment: "You cannot install packages (even public ones) from the GitHub npm registry without being authenticated." - where exactly are you getting this information? From the GitHub Docs you quoted?

Comment: The first line in https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-npm-registry#authenticating-to-github-packages reads: "You need an access token to publish, install, and delete packages.". I haven't tried recently and the sentence is a bit ambiguous but I believe that's what they mean.
But again, I haven't tried recently, this info is based on some trials I did last year.

Answer (score 0):

The docs should be updated.

> You need an access token to publish, install, and delete packages.

This should really be changed to;

> You need an access token to publish, install, and delete both private and public packages.

Comment: I created a [pull request](https://github.com/github/docs/pull/19552).